# How do you get ffmpeg-devel for Mac OSX without installing from source?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

How do you get the ffmpeg-devel for Mac OSX without installing from the source from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You extract it from the source on the web site. FFmpeg is not a standard system library on Mac OS X, so neither the library nor the development files are distributed in any official format.

Comment: Actually, I used homebrew and that worked as I searched for system files in the finder when looking for *.dylib files from ffmpeg.